# Preferred content height not working in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm presenting view controller(embedded with navigation controller) as form sheet, setting the preferred content size changes the width of presented view but height is always from top to bottom. Following is my code

```
let chooseCategoryNavController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "stbIdChooseCatehoryManufacturerNavVC") as? UINavigationController


            chooseCategoryNavController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet
            chooseCategoryNavController?.transitioningDelegate = self
        chooseCategoryNavController?.presentationController!.delegate = self


        if let aController = chooseCategoryNavController?.viewControllers.first as? ChooseCategoryManufacturerViewController
        {
            aController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 300)

        }

            chooseCategoryNavController?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 300)

            self.present(chooseCategoryNavController!, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

How can I customize height? As above code doesn't seem to affect height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and put this line of code right before frame properties changes.